# How do i add more slideshows in template?

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I've tried adding "mySlides3" but it doesnt work..
[here is my template.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_multiple)

Comment: Try this - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMK81QIBWVYD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
.mySlides1, .mySlides2 {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Multiple Slideshows</h2>

<p>Slideshow 1:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fd2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net%2Fvideo%2Fthumbnail%2FhHeEEOX%2Flovatnet-lake-beautiful-nature-norway_bpxjbou08l_thumbnail-full01.png&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fthewowstyle.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F01%2Fnature-images..jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides1">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.hdqwalls.com%2Fdownload%2Fbest-nature-image-2560x1440.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<p>Slideshow 2:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcroatia.hr%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fstyles%2Fimage_full_width%2Fpublic%2F2017-08%2F02_01_slide_nature.jpg%3Fitok%3DItAHmLlp&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fthewowstyle.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F01%2FFree-Wallpaper-Nature-Scenes.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides2">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.superiorwallpapers.com%2Fdownload%2Fsummer-sunny-day-and-wonderful-waterfall-in-the-nature-4550x2559.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<p>Slideshow 3:</p>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pixelstalk.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F09%2FBest-Desktop-Backgrounds-Nature.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwallup.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F01%2F132930-nature-landscape-flowers.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides3">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pixelstalk.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F08%2FWonderful-Nature-Colorful-Scene-HD.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = [1,1,1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```